# Comparing string/char with string/char literal in C++ in a localization safe way

Tags: c++, character-encoding, string-comparison, string-literals

How do I compare a character (`char`) or a string (`char*`, `std::string`, `std::wstring`, and so on) with a corresponding literal such that it is safe to localization and varying character encodings in different runtime environments?

Lets take the following minimal example as a start.

```
using namespace std;
// Get runtime locale and apply it to i/o streams
locale loc( "" );
cout.imbue( loc );
cin.imbue( loc );

// Ask question and compare answer
char c = '\0';
do {
    cout << "Important question [y/n]" << endl;
    cin >> c;
} while( c != 'n' && c != 'y' );

if( c == 'n' ) {
  // execute 'no'-branch
} else {
  // execute 'yes'-branch
}
```

(I know the example could be improved in many ways. The input stream should be cleared before reading the next character and so on. But this is not the point here.)

My problem is that a character `c` that comes from the environment is compared to a hard-coded literal `'n'` and despite the name of the type of the variable `char` we do not actually compare characters (or graphemes) but single bytes on a bit-wise level.

During compile time the literal `'n'` is translated to the execution character set. If the compiler is gcc under Linux this defaults to UTF-8. But this is not guaranteed, because the standard only requires a code set that covers certain characters. So actually every compiler is free to choose a suitable character set. But anyway, let's assume `'n'` gets translated to `'\x6e'` by the compiler for a moment.

However, the runtime environment can use a totally different encoding. Assume that the environment uses UTF-16. If the user types "n" the input stream is filled with the two byte sequence `"\x00\x6e"`. Hereof, `cin >> c` reads the first byte `'\x00'` and compares it to `'\x6e'`. Obviously, this is not what is intended.

Moreover, things become worse if we want to split a string into tokens. There are several functions for it (C's `strtok`, `boost::tokenize`), but basically they all do what `strtok` does. They take an input string and a string of characters that shall be used as delimiter symbols. But again, these function to not work on characters but on bytes.

Let's take this simple example

```
strtok( "alice, bob; charlie", ",;" );
```

By intention the first string should be split either at "," or at ";". Furthermore, lets assume that by some unknown miracle both strings are fortunately encoded by the same character encoding UTF-16. Although both strings have the same encoding the result is a total loss, because `",;"` is the four byte sequence `"\x00\x2c\x00\x3b"` and the first string is a 40-byte sequence with every second byte being `'\x00'`. Because `strtok` (and `boost::tokenize` and other) work on bytes, the result is bogus.

I know there is also `std::wstring` and since C++11 there additionally is `std::u16string` and `std::u32string` but they are no real rescue. (I do not want to elaborate on them, because the question is already long enough.)

Of course, there are 3rd party libraries like IBM's ICU or complete frameworks like Qt that avoid all these problems, but all these libraries solve the issue by defining their own string class.

On the one hand, these libraries are mostly incompatible with each other or if one wants to combine those libraries one must do a lot of type conversion and string copying. On the other hand, I usually write only small command line utilities and I do not want to create a dependence to a really huge library like Qt just to do a task like the first example of this question.

I cannot believe that for such a trivial problem like comparing a character to `'y'` or `'n'` there is no "standard" solution that only uses C++ Standard library. So back to my original question:

How do I compare a character (`char`) or a string (`char*`, `std::string`, `std::wstring`, and so on) with a corresponding literal such that it is safe to localization and varying character encodings in different runtime environments **with as little dependence to other libraries as necessary**?

Comment: "I cannot believe that for such a trivial problem like comparing a character to 'y' or 'n' there is no "standard" solution that only uses C++ Standard library." - 

Sadly, that's exactly the case.

Answer (score 0):

You open a narrow-character stream in the text mode, read some characters, and compare them to your literals. That's it. It works **by definition**. The character that compares equal to `'n'` **is** `'n'`, as defined by your implementation.

What guarantees that the `'n'` character that your implementation understands is the ASCII `n` or the EBCDIC `n` or whatever? Nothing. The mapping between your execution character set and the character set used by the environment is implementation-defined. The mapping may be locale-dependent so you have a chance to choose between several mapping by setting an appropriate locale. You need to consult your implementation documentation, or just blindly trust that (the lower half of) the mapping is given by ASCII. Fortunately, sane implementations provide a mapping that JustWorks™, and insane implementations don't survive for long.

Regarding your example with a UTF-16 string, unless the implementation promises that its *narrow* character set maps 1:1 to UTF-16 or a portion thereof (in some locale), you use wchar_t and an appropriate locale, or (since C++11) char16_t and `u16` literals. That's basically what they are for.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to state that `cin >> c` already performs the conversion from the runtime character set to the internal character set such that `c == 'n'` does the right thing? But then the question is what happens if this implicit conversion fails? For example, because the user types a character that does not fit into a single `char`? Does "cin >> c" throws an exception in this case?

Comment: There is no "internal character set" and "runtime character set", there is only one execution character set. There is no char-to-char translation, unless you use a custom `codecvt` facet. Microsoft implementations may or may not behave differently. Members of the basic execution character set are not locale-dependent anyway.